# comparing android intent objects

Tags: android, comparison, android-intent

I have 2 android intent objects that can be persisted as URLs and then rehydrated back into intent objects.  I'm wondering what is the most effective way to compare any 2 intent objects to ensure that they end up resolving to the same activity with the same parameters etc.  Using `intent.filterEquals` does this, but it does not include the extras.

Currently my code for the `equals` method looks like this:

```
            Intent a = Intent.parseUri(this.intentUrl,
                    Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);

            Intent b = Intent.parseUri(other.intentUrl,
                    Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
            if (a.filterEquals(b)) {
                if (a.getExtras() != null && b.getExtras() != null) {
                    for (String key : a.getExtras().keySet()) {
                        if (!b.getExtras().containsKey(key)) {
                            return false;
                        } else if (!a.getExtras().get(key)
                                .equals(b.getExtras().get(key))) {
                            return false;

                        }
                    }
                }
                // all of the extras are the same so return true
                return true;
            } else { return false; }
```

But is there  a better/cleaner way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably as good as it gets, at least conceptually. However, I don't think your algorithm covers cases where `b` has a key that `a` does not.

I'd get both `keySet()` values and run an `equals()` on those, to confirm they both have the same keys. Then, iterate over one and run `equals()` on the value pair.

Comment: good point.  perhaps a simpler way would be to just check that each keySet has the same size first?  if they don't have the same size, you know they're not the same, if they DO have the same size keyset and each value in a == b or they're not the same.  see any flaws in that you can think of?

Comment: @Ben: It would be `equals()`, not `==`, as in your original code. Otherwise, that should work.

Comment: @Ben: Oh, OK. Consider what I wrote to be a pseudo comment. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Improving upon @aostiles' answer by adding the missing return statement and also  conditions to compare arrays in extras:

```
private boolean intentsAreEqual (Intent a, Intent b)
    {
        if (a.filterEquals(b)) {
            if (a.getExtras() != null && b.getExtras() != null) {
                // check if the keysets are the same size
                if (a.getExtras().keySet().size() != b.getExtras().keySet().size()) return false;
                // compare all of a's extras to b
                for (String key : a.getExtras().keySet()) {
                    if (!b.getExtras().containsKey(key)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if (a.getExtras().get(key).getClass().isArray() && b.getExtras().get(key).getClass().isArray()) {
                        if (!Arrays.equals((Object[]) a.getExtras().get(key), (Object[]) b.getExtras().get(key))) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!a.getExtras().get(key).equals(b.getExtras().get(key))) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                // compare all of b's extras to a
                for (String key : b.getExtras().keySet()) {
                    if (!a.getExtras().containsKey(key)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if (b.getExtras().get(key).getClass().isArray() && a.getExtras().get(key).getClass().isArray()) {
                        if (!Arrays.equals((Object[]) b.getExtras().get(key), (Object[]) a.getExtras().get(key))) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!b.getExtras().get(key).equals(a.getExtras().get(key))) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            if (a.getExtras() == null && b.getExtras() == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            // either a has extras and b doesn't or b has extras and a doesn't
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much an implementation of what CommonsWare suggested combined with Ben's code but also covers the case where either `a` has extras and `b` does not or `b` has extras and `a` does not.

```
private boolean areEqual(Intent a, Intent b) {
    if (a.filterEquals(b)) {
        if (a.getExtras() != null && b.getExtras() != null) {
            // check if the keysets are the same size
            if (a.getExtras().keySet().size() != b.getExtras().keySet().size()) return false;
            // compare all of a's extras to b
            for (String key : a.getExtras().keySet()) {
                if (!b.getExtras().containsKey(key)) {
                    return false;
                } else if (!a.getExtras().get(key).equals(b.getExtras().get(key))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            // compare all of b's extras to a
            for (String key : b.getExtras().keySet()) {
                if (!a.getExtras().containsKey(key)) {
                    return false;
                } else if (!b.getExtras().get(key).equals(a.getExtras().get(key))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (a.getExtras() == null && b.getExtras() == null) return true;
        // either a has extras and b doesn't or b has extras and a doesn't
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like this implementation has a bug.  Shouldn't you return true after the second for loop?  Another thing to consider is checking if a == b at the beginning of the method.  That way many expensive tests can be skipped.