# The Expected result is the same as the Actual result, why it shows me they are different?

Tags: android

I use Robolectric today,however,I meet some problem that I can not find the solution.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainActivityTest：

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class,sdk=21)
public class MainActivityTest {
    @Test
    public void testMainActivity() {
        MainActivity mainActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
        mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.textView1).performClick();
        Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(mainActivity, SecondActivity.class);
        ShadowActivity shadowActivity = Shadows.shadowOf(mainActivity);
        Intent actualIntent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivity();
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedIntent, actualIntent);
    }
}
```

error message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: android.content.Intent<Intent { cmp=com.example.wyb.test/.SecondActivity }> but was: android.content.Intent<Intent { cmp=com.example.wyb.test/.SecondActivity }>
Expected :android.content.Intent<Intent { cmp=com.example.wyb.test/.SecondActivity }> 
Actual   :android.content.Intent<Intent { cmp=com.example.wyb.test/.SecondActivity }>     
Process finished with exit code 255
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.wyb.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3.2"

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I do not understand why Expected result is the same as Actual result, it still failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assertEquals` will call the `equals` method on the compared objects, but `equals` is not overridden on `Intent`, so I assume it's just doing an object reference comparison.

Try using [filterEquals](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals%28android.content.Intent%29) to compare Intents.

```
Assert.assertTrue(actualIntent.filterEquals(expectedIntent));
```

If `filterEquals` is not enough for you (it ignores extras), see [this question about comparing intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985227/comparing-android-intent-objects).